# IQueryable: Project columns by their names in linq dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda, linq-to-entities

I have a `Dictionary<string, string> Fields` that contains **propertyNames** and **property Types**.

and I have a query object: `IQueryable<T> query = GetQuery();`

I am using Typebuilder to build a type dynamically according to the Fields dictionary:

```
TypeBuilder builder = CreateTypeBuilder("MyDynamicAssembly", "MyModule", "MyType");

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

foreach (var s in Fields)
{
   CreateAutoImplementedProperty(builder, s.Key, Type.GetType(s.Value));
   dt.Columns.Add(s.Key, Type.GetType(s.Value));
}

Type resultType = builder.CreateType();
```

I want to modify the query object using `linq` to project only columns that their names are in the `Fields` dictionary. Something like:

```
dynamic queryResult = query.Take(10).Select("Don't know how to project here???");
```

consider the column names are:

```
string[] columnsNames = Fields.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Will be easier to understand if you show some sample data and output

Comment: Because you're building queries dynamically at run time, you need to build the expression tree dynamically. You can use this library to help with that: https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: @Gilad Green I added some more info

Comment: `string[] columnsNames = Fields.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();`
`string columns = string.Join(",", columnsNames);`
`dynamic queryResult = query.Take(10).Select("new (" + columns + ")");`

Comment: You can try that library with my example code. The `.Select` is the extension method from that library. Please let me know if it works.

Comment: @Khanh TO thank you very much! it absolutely works. I know it's another question but if I want to add a contains() predicate for all columns that are projected I mean: (Name.Contains("searchvalue") || Code.Contains("SearchValue")) is it possible by using dynamic linq?

Comment: I think it's possible by building the `Where` clause dynamically.

Comment: @Khanh TO is there any short way for that? like the answer you posted? or should I build expression trees?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156733/discussion-between-khanh-to-and-karamafrooz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're building queries dynamically at run time, you need to build the **expression tree** dynamically. You can use this library to help with that: https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

In your case, you can build your `.Select` clause dynamically like this:

```
string[] columnsNames = Fields.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();

string columns = string.Join(",", columnsNames);

dynamic queryResult = query.Take(10).Select("new (" + columns + ")");
```

The `.Select` above is the extension method from that library